# Javascript events - how to make this code DRY

Tags: javascript, dom-events, dry

I'm learning JavaScript. Can somebody help me to make this code DRY (don't repeat yourself) please? The code is about changing color of paragraph by clicking on particular `connected-with` button. I have no idea how to make the `changeColor` function applicable for particular block of code without making a new version of this function.

```
var greenPar = document.getElementById("green-paragraph");
var greenColorBtn = document.getElementById("greenColorBtn");
var redPar = document.getElementById("red-paragraph");
var redColorBtn = document.getElementById("redColorBtn");
greenColorBtn.addEventListener("click", changeColorGreen);
redColorBtn.addEventListener("click", changeColorRed);

function changeColorGreen() {
    if (greenPar.className == "") {
        greenPar.className = "green"; //.green{ color:green;}
    } else {
        greenPar.className = "";
    }
}

function changeColorRed() {
    if (redPar.className == "") {
        redPar.className = "red"; //.red{ color:red;}
    } else {
        redPar.className = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it repeat itself? I don't get what you mean? note: you can use "redPar.className.length > 0" instead of redPar.className == ""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use common function as click handler and pass color value as argument.

As you will be using `this` value in handler, use [**`Function#bind`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) and pass `this-context`, 
 second argument will be color value to be compared.

```js
var greenPar = document.getElementById("green-paragraph");
var greenColorBtn = document.getElementById("greenColorBtn");

var redPar = document.getElementById("red-paragraph");
var redColorBtn = document.getElementById("redColorBtn");

greenColorBtn.addEventListener("click", changeColor.bind(greenColorBtn, 'green'));
redColorBtn.addEventListener("click", changeColor.bind(redColorBtn, 'red'));

function changeColor(color) {
  var thisElem = this;
  if (thisElem.className == "") {
    thisElem.className = color;
  } else {
    thisElem.className = "";
  }
}
```

Comment: Damn, beat me to it. Also if you're not using the `greenPar` or `redPar` elsewhere you could add the selector as a param to `changeColor()` and do the `document.getElementById()` in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `changeColor` function in an anonymous function so that you can pass arguments:

```
var greenPar = document.getElementById("green-paragraph");
var greenColorBtn = document.getElementById("greenColorBtn");

var redPar = document.getElementById("red-paragraph");
var redColorBtn = document.getElementById("redColorBtn");

greenColorBtn.addEventListener("click", function () { changeColor(greenPar, "green"); });
redColorBtn.addEventListener("click", function () { changeColor(redPar, "red"); });

function changeColor(element, value){
    if(element.className == ""){
        elmement.className = value;
    }else{
        element.className = "";
    }  
}
```

Comment: You are only changing `greenPar` here

Comment: I'm sorry. My mistake. I should double check what I write. It should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
   function getElementByid (_id) {
     var element = document.getElementById(_id);
     return element;
    }

    function changeColor (_id,_colorClass) {
        var element=getElementByid (_id);
        if (element.className==""){
            element.className=_colorClass;
        }else {
            element.className="";
        }
    }
    getElementByid ("greenColorBtn").addEventListener("click",
        changeColor ("green-paragraph","green"));

    getElementByid ("redColorBtn").addEventListener("click",
        changeColor ("red-paragraph","red")); `
```